# AdminLTE JavaScript problem with iFrame Cannot read properties of null (reading 'autoIframeMode')

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, iframe

Im using AdminLTE free Bootstrap admin template for a simple web app.
In normal browser window everything is working. Im embedding the adminLTE based app via iframe.
I get constant errors when embedding adminlte html inside iframe.
Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'autoIframeMode') IFrame.js:271
at e.t._initFrameElement (IFrame.js:271:45)
at S.fn.init.e._jQueryInterface [as IFrame] (IFrame.js:434:88)
at IFrame.js:445:27
at dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
```

Its trying to append css class iframe-mode to body tag (code from adminlte.js)

```
_initFrameElement() {
    if (window.frameElement && this._config.autoIframeMode) {
      const $body = $('body')
      $body.addClass(CLASS_NAME_IFRAME_MODE)
```

Tried to turn off autoiframe mode for AdminLTE following its documentation. https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1/javascript/iframe.html
Added in html  tag:

```
<script>  
$('.content-wrapper').IFrame({
  onTabClick(item) {
    return item
  },
  onTabChanged(item) {
    return item
  },
  onTabCreated(item) {
    return item
  },
  autoIframeMode: false,
  autoItemActive: true,
  autoShowNewTab: true,
  allowDuplicates: true,
  loadingScreen: 750,
  useNavbarItems: true
})  
</script>
```

This jquery is throwing an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How to turn off this appending of iframe-mode class to body tag?
(prevent automatic adminlte iframe mode)

Comment: Solved by upgrading AdminLTE to v 3.2.0

Answer (score 6):

To disable this component you need to setup you configuration via localstorage before you load the template js

```
localStorage.setItem('AdminLTE:IFrame:Options',JSON.stringify({autoIframeMode:false,autoItemActive:false}))
```

This will be loaded when the plugin is initialiazed:

```
static _jQueryInterface(config) {
    if ($(SELECTOR_DATA_TOGGLE).length > 0) {
      let data = $(this).data(DATA_KEY)

      if (!data) {
        data = $(this).data()
      }

      const _options = $.extend({}, Default, typeof config === 'object' ? config : data)
      localStorage.setItem('AdminLTE:IFrame:Options', JSON.stringify(_options))

      const plugin = new IFrame($(this), _options)

      $(this).data(DATA_KEY, typeof config === 'object' ? config : data)

      if (typeof config === 'string' && /createTab|openTabSidebar|switchTab|removeActiveTab/.test(config)) {
        plugin[config]()
      }
    } else {
      new IFrame($(this), JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('AdminLTE:IFrame:Options')))._initFrameElement()
    }
  }
```